# How could one improve this code so that it is more concise and efficient?

Tags: vb.net, optimization

**Visual Basic**

This is the final section of code of a program I have written.The final section (shown below) displays the receipt. However, it has a lot of repeated code so I figure it can be improved by some better code. But, I'm not sure how to do this.

So, could you please improve the code so that it is shorter and more concise (maybe with a loop?) and write out the improved code. I'd much appreciate it if you could also explain the improved code.

Here is the code in Visual Basic that I would like you to improve:

```
    Dim itemName (4) As String
    Dim priceOfItem(4) As Decimal 
    Dim amountOrdered(4) As Decimal 
    'the "completePriceOfItem" array is simply the "priceOfItem" multipled by the "amountOrdered" but ,as this is only a... 
    '...part of my program, this has already been processed and assigned to the aray.
    Dim completePriceOfItem(4) As Decimal
    'setting  up variables
    Dim numberOfItems As Integer = 0

    'final section of program where it displays the receipt
    Console.WriteLine("Receipt:")
    Console.WriteLine
    If numberOfItems = 1 Then
        Console.WriteLine(itemName(0) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(0), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(0) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(0), "Currency") & " in total")
    ElseIf numberOfItems = 2 Then
        Console.WriteLine(itemName(0) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(0), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(0) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(0), "Currency") & " in total")
        Console.WriteLine(itemName(1) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(1), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(1) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(1), "Currency") & " in total")
    ElseIf numberOfItems = 3 Then
        Console.WriteLine(itemName(0) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(0), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(0) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(0), "Currency") & " in total")
        Console.WriteLine(itemName(1) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(1), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(1) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(1), "Currency") & " in total")
        Console.WriteLine(itemName(2) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(2), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(2) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(2), "Currency") & " in total")
    ElseIf numberOfItems = 4 Then
        Console.WriteLine(itemName(0) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(0), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(0) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(0), "Currency") & " in total")
        Console.WriteLine(itemName(1) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(1), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(1) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(1), "Currency") & " in total")
        Console.WriteLine(itemName(2) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(2), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(2) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(2), "Currency") & " in total")
        Console.WriteLine(itemName(3) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(3), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(3) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(3), "Currency") & " in total") 
    ElseIf numberOfItems = 5 Then
        Console.WriteLine(itemName(0) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(0), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(0) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(0), "Currency") & " in total")
        Console.WriteLine(itemName(1) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(1), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(1) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(1), "Currency") & " in total")
        Console.WriteLine(itemName(2) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(2), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(2) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(2), "Currency") & " in total")
        Console.WriteLine(itemName(3) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(3), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(3) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(3), "Currency") & " in total") 
        Console.WriteLine(itemName(4) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(4), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(4) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(4), "Currency") & " in total")
    End If
    Console.ReadLine
```

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that I am a beginner programmer.

Comment: Looks an awful lot like a question you'd get in an introductory programming class. Trying to get us to do your homework ?

Comment: No. That's my own question, honestly.

Comment: For this kind of basic stuff, why don't you follow a tutorial on language basics such as loops? This is not really the kind of question where you need Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple `for` loop. Replace your `if` logic with the following...

```
For index As Integer = 0 To numberOfItems - 1
    Console.WriteLine(itemName(index) & ": " & Format (priceOfItem(index), "Currency") & " each" & ", " & amountOrdered(index) & " bought" & ", " & Format (completePriceOfItem(index), "Currency") & " in total")
Next
```

The variable `index` is incremented each loop meaning that you can replace your `0`, `1`, `2` etc. with the variable name "`index`" to pull the data at the correct index.

The loop will run the number of times defined in your `numberOfItems` variable.

Comment: Should it not be 0 To `numberofItems - 1` ?

Comment: Yes it should. Corrected

Comment: Thank you. This worked very well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would make this code better.

I'd create a few classes. One for an `Order`, and one for an `OrderLine`:

```
Public Class Order

    Public Property Lines As List(Of OrderLine)

    Public Sub New()
        Lines = New List(Of OrderLine)()

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class OrderLine

    Public Property itemName As String


    Public Property priceOfItem As Decimal

    Public Property amountOrdered As Decimal

    Public ReadOnly Property CompletePriceOfItem() As Decimal
        Get
            Return priceOfItem * amountOrdered
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Then I would change the `Main` code like this:

```
Dim Orders As List(Of Order) = New List(Of [Order])()

'Create a new Order, and add OrderLine to it
Dim o As New Order()
Dim ol As OrderLine

ol = New OrderLine()
ol.itemName = "Item1"
ol.priceOfItem = 10.99
ol.amountOrdered = 3

o.Lines.Add(ol)

Orders.Add(o)

'final section of program where it displays the receipt
Console.WriteLine("Receipt:")
Console.WriteLine()

For Each ord As Order In Orders

    For Each ordline As OrderLine In ord.Lines
        Console.WriteLine(ordline.itemName & ": " & Format(ordline.priceOfItem, "Currency") & " each" & ", " & ordline.amountOrdered & " bought" & ", " & Format(ordline.completePriceOfItem, "Currency") & " in total")

    Next
Next

Console.ReadLine()
```

So, instead of hard coding the number of items, I use `List(Of...)` which can grow as needed.

Also, using a class for `OrderLine` removes the need for separate arrays.

Finally, instead of having a separate array for the `CompletePriceOfItem`, I let the class' property handle the calculation.

This is just a rough concept for now, but I think you'll get the idea.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: I see you preferred the other solution. Could you explain why ? Is my solution too difficult, or do you find issues with it ? I'd like to get better at answering questions, so your feedback will help me improve the quality of my answers.

Comment: As I am just a beginner, I didn't really understand your code ( for example, I don't really know what public, private and class stuff are). But, it looked like you put a lot of effort into your answer so I am still thankful for your help. :)

Comment: I understand. When I read your question, I thought you might be interested in learning how this kind of situation would be handled in a "real life" fashion. Classes are one of the pillars of Object Oriented Programming. Do keep this page in reference for later, once you have gone beyond the bare basics of VB.NET. Have fun learning :-)